# Use Youtube thumbnails in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, thumbnails, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to load Youtube video thumbnails in a RecyclerView. I'm getting this error when call initialize() method.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit:              Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
```

This is my recyclerView adapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Song> songsList;

public DataAdapter(Context mContext, List<Song> songsList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.songsList = songsList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return songsList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView song_title, song_author;
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        song_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        song_author = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_author);

        youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_row, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Song song = songsList.get(position);
    holder.song_title.setText(song.getTitle());
    holder.song_author.setText(song.getAuthor());

    holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(videoID);
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    });
}
```

And in MainActivity, I'm calling DataAdapter like this:

```
mAdapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this, songs);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use below URL for Download the thumbnail of specific video
http://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/default.jpg by replacing the VIDEO_ID with actual video id of YouTube.

For Example you have youtube Video url is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47S-Wn4EYdU` then the Thumbnail image URL will be `http://img.youtube.com/vi/47S-Wn4EYdU/default.jpg`, you have to download this image and set it to `holder.youTubeThumbnailView`

**Example**

*Adapter.java*

```
String YOUTUBE_URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47S-Wn4EYdU";
    String[] strUrlText = YOUTUBE_URL.split("=");
                    String strURL = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+strUrlText[1]+"/default.jpg";


                    Images_Download imgs_Download = new Images_Download(context, imageView);
                    imgs_Download.execute(strURL);

                    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent in = new Intent(context, Youtube_Player_Activity.class);
                            in.putExtra("URL", YOUTUBE_URL);
                            context.startActivity(in);
                        }
                    });
```

**Youtube_Player_Activity.java**

```
public class Youtube_Player_Activity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    String url = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_player_activity);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null)
        {           
            url = bundle.getString("URL");
        }

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        youTubeView.initialize(SecurityInfo.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
.....
}
```

Comment: And how can I do that? The app crashes before enter initialize() method

Comment: don't initialize it in Adapter class, in adapter just show the Thumbnail image in imageView and onClick of imageView open new activity and Initialize there.

Comment: I'm going to use YoutubeStandalonePlayer. My idea is add a play button and createvideointent in OnBindViewHolder on Adapter class. Like this: holder.play_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity)mContext, ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, song.getYoutubeId(), 0, true, false);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Comment: its depend on your need which one is perfect for you, i have just suggested you an idea to do so. you can use any of one.